# Expressing Domain of Discourse and Its Restriction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, quantifiers

When I was studying quantifiers and its notation, I found that in general, if given a domain of discourse $D$:

We can express the universal quantification as $$\forall x \in D \space P(x) \iff \forall x (x \in D \rightarrow P(x))$$ And we can express the existential quantification as $$\exists x \in D \space P(x) \iff \exists x (x \in D \space \wedge \space P(x))$$

However, my question is that, what if I wanted to *restrict* the given domain of discourse?

For instance, if I wanted to express "the square of a negative real number is positive", how would I be able to express $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall x < 0$ at the same time in one expression?

Here is my attempt:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \space \mid \space \forall x< 0 \space P(x) \iff \forall x(x \in \mathbb{R} \space \mid \space x < 0 \rightarrow P(x))$$

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: The way is to use explicit formulas, like in your last attemp: $\forall x [(x \in \mathbb R \land x < 0) \to P(x)]$.

Answer (score 1):

> what if I wanted to *restrict* the given domain of discourse? For instance, if I wanted to express "the square of a negative real number is positive"

Three ways to formalise "the square of each negative real number is positive":

$$\forall x \;\big(x\in\mathbb R\;\land\; x<0\;\to\; P(x) \big) \\
\forall x{\in}\mathbb R \;\big(x<0\to P(x) \big) \\
\forall x{\in}(-\infty,0) \;\, P(x). $$